# Generate SASS mixins with gulp-svg-sprite?

Tags: svg, gulp, sprite

Im using the gulp-svg-sprite plugin.

https://github.com/jkphl/gulp-svg-sprite

https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite

I already have my classes and styles which I would like to sprite:

```
    .header {
      background: grey;

      &:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        background: url(images/icon1.svg);
      }
    }
```

This is my gulp task:

```
    spriteConfig    = {
      mode          : {
        css        : {
          bust      : true,
          render    : {
            scss    : true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    gulp.task('sprite', function() {
      gulp.src('images/svg/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite(spriteConfig))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
    });
```

The task generates this type of SASS:

```
    %svg-common {
        background: url("svg/sprite.css-c3700f6a.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .svg-icon1 {
        @extend %svg-common;
        background-position: 50% 0;
    }

    .svg-icon1-dims {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 348px;
    }
```

This isnt ideal as I need to import these svg- classes which I wont use on there own, and I then need to use 2 extends:

```
    .header {
      background: grey;

      &:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        @extend .svg-icon1;
        @extend .svg-icon1-dims;
      }
    }
```

Is there a way of generating mixins instead so I could jsut have something like:

```
    .header {
      background: grey;

      &:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        @include svg-icon1;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite):

> It comes with a set of Mustache templates for creating stylesheets in
>   good ol' CSS or one of the major pre-processor formats (Sass, Less and
>   Stylus). Tweaking the templates or even adding your own custom output
>   format is really easy, just as switching on the generation of an HTML
>   example document along with your sprite.

Have a look and customize the following file:

https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite/blob/master/tmpl/css/sprite.scss

Answer (score 1):

Danny H was correct. Here is my code. Notice that ive also used a prefix in my spriteConfig.

```
spriteConfig    = {
  mode          : {
    css         : {
      bust      : true,
      prefix    : "@mixin sprite-%s",
      render    : {
        scss: {
          template: 'sprite.scss.handlebars'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In sprite.scss.handlebars:

```
{{#hasMixin}}@mixin {{mixinName}} {
    background: url("{{{sprite}}}") no-repeat;
}

{{#hasCommon}}.{{commonName}} {
    @include {{mixinName}};
}

{{/hasCommon}}{{/hasMixin}}{{^hasMixin}}{{#hasCommon}}.{{/hasCommon}}{{^hasCommon}}@mixin {{/hasCommon}}{{commonName}} {
    background: url("{{{sprite}}}") no-repeat;
}

{{/hasMixin}}{{#shapes}}{{#selector.shape}}{{expression}}{{^last}},
{{/last}}{{/selector.shape}} {
    {{^hasCommon}}{{#hasMixin}}@include {{mixinName}};{{/hasMixin}}{{^hasMixin}}@include {{commonName}};{{/hasMixin}}
    {{/hasCommon}}background-position: {{position.relative.xy}};{{#dimensions.inline}}
    width: {{width.outer}}px;
    height: {{height.outer}}px;{{/dimensions.inline}}
    width: {{width.outer}}px;
    height: {{height.outer}}px;
}

{{/shapes}}
```